# VBA: Trying to loop over files and getting an overflow error

Tags: vba, loops, overflow, logfile

I am trying to do an analyses with multiple log-files. I would like to count how often a certain page was opened by the users. Therefore I try to loop over all log-files in a directory and to look in these files in a second Loop. 
The Inner Loop which Looks in the files worked when I was testing it with just a single file. But now i added an Outer Loop which Loops over the files in the directory and now a get an `Overflow error` in `line 15`. I am very new to VBA but I don't understand why this is happening because the `Do-Loop` should end at the end of every file due to the `EOF(1)` condition.

I hope someone can help me please! Thanks a lot.

```
'Begin Outer-Loop
Dim FSO, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = FSO.GetFolder("n:\logs\logs\")

For Each file In MySource.Files

'Begin Inner-Loop
    intRow = 1
    Close
    Open file For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, strText
        intRow = intRow + 1

'Management-Counter
        If strText Like "*Management Overview" Then
            management_counter = management_counter + 1
        End If

'Automation-Counter
        If strText Like "*Automation Rate" Then
            automation_counter = automation_counter + 1
        End If

'Changes-Counter
        If strText Like "*Changes" Then
            changes_counter = changes_counter + 1
        End If

'Touchrate-Counter
        If strText Like "*Touchrate" Then
            touchrate_counter = touchrate_counter + 1
        End If

'Delivery Performance-Counter
        If strText Like "*4. Delivery Performance" Then
            delPerformance_counter = delPerformance_counter + 1
        End If

'Delivery Performance - Date Changes-Counter
        If strText Like "*Date Changes" Then
            dateChanges_counter = dateChanges_counter + 1
        End If

'Delivery Performance - Delivery Reliability-Counter
        If strText Like "*Delivery Reliability" Then
            delivery_counter = delivery_counter + 1
        End If

'End Inner Loop
    Loop

'End Outer Loop
Next file


End Sub
```

Comment: Can't be sure since you don't have all your declarations included, but change `intRow` and all your counters to `Long` if they aren't already.

Comment: Note: a lot of overflow errors involving counters are from the counters being `Integer` instead of `Long`. I don't see the declaration of your variables, so I don't know if that's the problem in this case or not.   (Also, _line 15_ is not a very helpful pointer, could you add a comment either right above or after the problem line?)

Comment: Please paste the error message you have and tell us in which line do you have the problem.